# How to find out the complxity of MapReduce algorithms in case of Hadoop Streaming.?

Tags: hadoop-streaming

I am right now using Python to run my programs and I want to estimate their exact time complexities.

But as it uses streams i.e. as it directly read the input from the HDFS file system, I am quite confused regarding its complexity.

For example: one of my program has complexity of O(n2) if local memory is used to store the complete input file. But after running it through streaming, it is actually taking much less time than original complexity of O(n2). I want its exact estimates i.e. How much time is reduced in case of reading an input directly from the HDFS File system ?

Please Help.